# Stopping Time Sum of Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

Let $X_1,...,X_t$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables with support $\{a,-b\}$, where $a,b>0$, and measure $P(a)=p_1$, $P(-b)=p_2$. Assume $p_1a-p_2b<0$, so that $E[X_t]<0$.

Let $S_t=\sum_{i=1}^t X_i$. It is straightforward to see that $S_t \rightarrow -\infty$.

Let $\tau$ be the stopping time corresponding to the first time that $S_t$ exceeds $M$ for some $M \in (-b,0]$,
$$\tau=\inf\{t \geq 1 \mid S_t \geq M\}$$
I am trying to figure out how to show that $P(\tau=\infty)>0$.

Comment: One knows that $S_t\to-\infty$ almost surely hence $Z=\sup S_t$ is finite almost surely. Choose $n$ large enough so that $P(Z<nb)>0$, and consider $A=\{X_1=\cdots=X_n=X_{n+1}=-b\}$. Then $P(\tau<\infty\mid A)=P(Z\geqslant M+(n+1)b)\leqslant P(Z\geqslant nb)$ hence $P(\tau<\infty\mid A)<1$. Since $P(A)>0$, this proves that $P(\tau<\infty)<1$.